# Fourier expansion of a kind twisted Eisenstein series

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The classical Eisenstein series admit the Fourier expansion
$$\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\\ gcd(m,n)=1} (m\tau+n)^{-k}=1+c \cdot \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{r|m}r^{k-1}e^{2\pi i m\tau}.$$
But, what if I have an additional congruence appears, i.e.
$$\sum_{m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\\ gcd(m,n)=1\\ m \equiv t \mod q} (m\tau+n)^{-k}?$$
($t$ and $q$ arbitrary)

If $t\equiv 0 \mod q$, then the proof of the Fourier expansion of the classical Eisenstein series can be adapted easily. Is this also possible for $t\not\equiv 0 \mod q$?

Comment: Your first formula is wrong, it is $a+c\sum_{k\ge 1}\sum_{r|k} r^{k-1}e^{2i\pi k \tau}$. For your question, use that $
\sum_{\gcd(m,n)=1} \frac{\chi(m)}{(m\tau+n)^k}=
\frac1{L(k,\chi)}\sum_{m,n\ne 0,0} \frac{\chi(m)}{(m\tau+n)^k}$. The RHS has an easy Fourier expansion. Then sum over the $\chi \bmod q$.

Comment: More generally, you can put any congruence condition $(m,n) \equiv (a,b) \bmod{N}$ in the sum. You will get an Eisenstein series of level $N$ (more precisely, for the principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(N)$). For details on the derivation of the Fourier expansion, you can look in Schoeneberg, *Elliptic modular functions*, Chapter 7.

Comment: I meant $a+c\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{r|n} r^{k-1}e^{2i\pi n \tau}$ sorry. And the sum over $\chi$ works better if $\gcd(t,q)=1$, if not there is an additional sum.

Comment: Thanks, guys. This helps me a lot.
@reuns: yeah, I've corrected the formula, thanks.